# what is the best archetype when using maven to create console application?

Tags: java, maven

I am wondering what's the best archetype when using maven to create console application, for example, junit and other plugin are all up to date?

Answer (score 1):

"best" is quite subjective in developer world, but i will use maven-archetype-quickstart

[maven-archetype-quickstart](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/)